# Interpolate new line from string in Pug

Tags: javascript, pug, nodemailer

I am using Pug with Nodemailer in a NodeJS server to handle email templates.

In my case I have the following object in the `locals` object

```js
{
    from: 'abc@xyz.com',
    message: 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne',
}
```

Now in the Pug file I have the following line

```js
p #{message}
```

The problem is that in the email I don't get the text with new lines.

The message filed ignores the `\n` and puts everything on the same line `a b c d e`

I need to get the text in the page with the new lines as it is in the object.

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

What would be the solution for this issue?

Comment: You're creating HTML, which ignores `\n`. You need to use `<br>` instead. Or use `<pre>` instead of `<p>`. Or use [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, the `<p>` tag ignores preformatting, maybe try using `<pre>` instead?

`pre #{message}`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use a `<p>` for each paragraph instead of a `<pre>` you can convert each newline into a new paragraph in Pug:

```
section
  each line in message.split('\n') 
    p #{line}
```

This will render:

```
<section>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>b</p>
  <p>c</p>
  <p>d</p>
  <p>e</p>
</section>
```

This assumes `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. in your example are actually blocks of text that you've shortened to create a quick example.